# PHP Dynamic webpage based on checkbox value change

Tags: php, html, mysql, dynamic, filter

My PHP code is echoing/generating HTML using while loop with data from mySQL.
Based on checkbox value (a field in MySQL table already shown with HTML), I want filter the populated HTML tags which I posted with data.

i.e If I select a check box for City = 'ABC' then all of the tags where I have populated using PHP with NOT city 'ABC' should be filtered out dynamically from web page.

Comment: And exactly what is your question?

Comment: show your code which try

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to remove data from the DOM upon applying a filter to your data. Look into javascript libraries that offer this functionality.